# problem to hide image when slideUp menu

Tags: jquery, visibility, slide, slidedown, slideup

I've a menu with slideUp and SlideDown.

The user clicks in menuArea and the menu is opened and an image with a cross becomes visible.
To close the button the user click in the image, and that image becomes invisible.

I'm having a problem in this step.

Look at this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pedroR/7YNJY/3/

NOTE: See this fiddle in Chrome or IE because of the image

Thanks

Comment: What exactly are you having problems with? Seems to work ok for me.

Comment: you would like to hide the image after clicking it to close the menu?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the `img` is contained within the `#menuText` element. That means when you click the `img` element, the click event handler for `#menuText` is also fired, and when that runs, it fades the `img` back in.

You can prevent that by adding an argument to the `img` click event handler, and calling `stopPropagation` to prevent the event from bubbling up:

```
$('#menuArea #menuText img').click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $('#menuArea ul').delay(100).slideUp(250);
    $(this).stop(true, true).delay(100).animate({
        opacity: 0
    }, '100', 'linear');
});
```

Here's a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/7YNJY/11/).

Answer (score 2):

http://jsfiddle.net/7YNJY/12/ here try this out. You can put the animate back in, but i just dumbed it down a little bit to make it easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

See if this is the result you are looking for: http://jsfiddle.net/rkw79/7YNJY/13/